# Where does SCP keep its Known_Hosts info

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I am looking for the file in which `scp` keeps known_hosts information. Can anyone direct me where this would be on Linux?

I have looked in my `$HOME/.ssh` directory but the information is not kept there. If it makes a difference, I am actually using Linux for Windows Subsystem.

Comment: That does not seem to be the case. I have already connected with SCP and checked the .ssh folder. A known_hosts file was not even created.

Comment: "No such file or directory" because the file does not exist. I also checked /etc/ssh.

Comment: The folder exists and has authorized_keys, id_rsa and id_rsa.pub.

Comment: I am not looking to create it. SCP is connecting and I want to find where it stored those details. It has to have stored the details somewhere for it to be connecting because the first time I connected it ask me if I wanted to trust the host and permanenly store connection details.

Comment: Run `scp -vvv ...` and you will know which files are used in the connection.

Comment: Thanks. I found it using scp -vvv. Because I ran scp with sudo, root's known_hosts file was used instead of my own in home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate verbose mode, i.e. run `scp -vvv ...`, in which all files used in the connection are printed explicitly.

For example, if user `joe` stores known hosts in standard file, `/home/.ssh/known_hosts`, then output during connection to `myhost` should look like:

```
[...]
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/joe/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/joe/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from myhost
debug1: Host 'myhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/joe/.ssh/known_hosts:3
[...]
```